# What will be the regex for the given case?

Tags: java, regex

I'm working on a regex for getting a specific number pattern from the URL string.

**Requirements:** Desire string should start from `-` or `/`, followed by a sequence of digits and ending with a `/` or nothing.

**I tried:** `[-\/](\d+)(\/|$)`, but for e.g. in `www.abc.com/pages/Toms-1777/14623420046` I want `/14623420046`(i.e. the second occurring digit sequence), but according to my regex, the result will be `-1777/`. I was trying negative lookbehind but not able to make any progress. I'm new to all this. Please guide.

**Test cases:** (with matched pattern)

www.abc.com/pages/Essen-Massage-Therapy-LLC`/130561253629638`

www.abc.com/biz/finn-mccools-santa-monica-2

www.abc.com/summerset.gardens.7

www.abc.com/pages/Toms-1777`/14623420046`

www.abc.com/pages/The-Clean-Masters`/1403753595526512`

www.abc.com/24hfsheepsheadbay

www.abc.com/sample2NVCoolSpace

www.abc.com/pages/Jet-Set-3920`/542495615847409`

www.abc.com/temp.buildings.77

www.abc.com/2423423453534temp`/2312312312312312312`

www.abc.com/Ptemp-Gtemp-Dtemp`-189398324428792/`temp

Comment: If you want the last match use `.*[-/](\d+)(/|$)`

Comment: In java you could get all matches from your Pattern object and choose the last one.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your regex contains 3 groups and it also matches the 1st group but I require only the other 2 groups. Thanks.

Comment: No idea whose regex you are talking about.Mine has two groups only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want that $ in either case. Instead of 'slash OR end', it's more 'optional slash and then a very much not-optional end'. So.. `/?$`. You don't need to normally escape slashes, especially in java regexes:

```
Pattern.compile("[-/](\\d+)/?$")
```

This reads: From minus or slash, a bunch of digits, then 0 or 1 slashes, then the end. Note, use `find()` and not `matches()` - matches only works if the entire string matches, which it won't, as the - or / occurs halfway through.

EDIT: Was missing a backslash in the java string.

Comment: Thanks @rzwitserloot